# Is it possible to make several calls in a single transaction?

Tags: transactions, dapp-development, gas, contract-invocation

Suppose your contract has a very simple function, `F()`, which takes about `1,000 gas` to process. Suppose you want to call that function 100 times. Since there is an overhead of about `21,000 gas` per transaction, you'll be paying `2,200,000 gas`. But, if your contract has a function:

```
function Fs(uint n){
    for (uint i=0; i<n; ++i)
        F();
}
```

You could perform the exact same operation with a single call, `Fs(100)`, which would cost only `121,000 gas`, a 94.5% reduction. Is there any way to send several calls to `F` in a single transaction, so you can achieve the same effect even when the contract didn't specifically optimize for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under what circumstance are you calling `F()` repeatedly?

Name the place where you're calling from `C()`. There's multiple possibilities:

1. `C()` and `F()` are in the same contract. In this situation, `C()` can call `F()` repeatedly without any major overhead.
2. `C()` is in one contract, and `F()` is in another contract. In this situation, `C()` can repeatedly call `F()` within the same transaction, but it will cost some gas each time. (Less than sending a separate transaction every time, however)
3. `C()` is outside of Ethereum entirely (i.e. a javascript function via web3) and `F()` is a constant function (that is, it does not modify the contract's state.) In this situation, `C()` can call `F()` as many times as it likes, for free. It will simulate transactions rather than actually sending them.
4. `C()` is outside of Ethereum, and `F()` is *non*-constant. In this situation, each transaction will cost the full amount. It's possible you can write another contract to call `F()` repeatedly, as in 2.

Note that there is a significant difference between a *transaction* and a *call*. Users create transactions, which may contain any number of calls. A call, also called an internal transaction or a message call, is when one account or transaction interacts with another. Contracts can only perform the latter.

(This terminology is somewhat obscure, and you'll probably find people confusing the two--I've done so myself.)

Comment: For #1, there's a case when it will cost as #2 and that's if F has been marked with `external` visibility (even though C and F are in the same contract), as in `function F() external ...`

Comment: You know, I don't think I've ever seen someone use the `external` modifier